# PlusShare.Builder on a Fragment

Tags: android, google-plus

In sharing a post to Google Plus, does PlusShare.Builder work only on an activity or is it possible to work on a fragment?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work in a Fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my eclipse i think had a bug. It doesn't include the bin file when adding the library. So i had to just import in manually. Thank you. :)